# Lyrics in Madoka Magica - Rebellion?

Tags: madoka-magica, music

I'm looking for lyrics on the songs in the Rebellion movie (original and translated), what are the lyrics for:

- Nightmare song (track #3)
- Mami's fight scene
- Mami's remixed theme
- "Dream world"
- "Noi!"
- "the worst ending"
- "I was waiting for this moment"

The only lyrics I've been able to find so far is for Made Dame Yo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics

Comment: I think this question should remain open - there's a good reason OP can't find lyrics for these songs, which I've pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> - Nightmare song (track #3)

Track #3 *is* "Mada Dame Yo", which you said you found lyrics for.

> - "Dream world" [#25]
> - "the worst ending" [#33]
> - "I was waiting for this moment" [#40]

The lyrics for these are in Kajiuran (cf. [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6723/1908)), which is not an actual language. Lyrics for pieces in Kajiuran are typically not released (though even if they were, you couldn't translate them, because, you know, it's not a language).

> - Mami's fight scene
> - Mami's remixed theme

If you can point me to the track numbers or titles for these, I can check on them (I don't remember off-hand which ones these were). Odds are, though, these are also in Kajiuran.

> - "Noi!" [#32]

The lyrics for this one are also not a real language. I would hesitate to call it "Kajiuran", just because it seems a lot more Germanic-inspired and less Romance-inspired than her usual stuff, but anyway, you're not going to find lyrics for this one either.